# Find the function $f(x)$ from given condition

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

> Consider a continuous and differentiable function $f(x)$ such that $$f(x)=x+\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin (x+y)f(y) dy$$ where $x, y$ are independent variables. Find $f(x)$

My try:

Differentiating both sides of given equation with respect to $x$ we get $$f'(x)=1+\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \cos(x+y) f(y) dy$$

Now we get  $$f'(\frac {\pi}{2} +x)=1-\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin (x+y) f(y) dy$$

Hence we get $$f'(\frac {\pi}{2}+x)=1-f(x)-x$$

But am not able continue further from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use the sine sum formula, it gives that $f(x)=x+a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$ for constants $a$ and $b$. Plugging this into the functional equation should get you $a$ and $b$, though it'll be a bit of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $$f'(x)=1+\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \cos(x+y) f(y)\,dy$$

we see that $f'$ is also differentiable and that

$$f''(x) = -\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin(x+y) f(y) dy = -f(x) + x$$

We obtain the simple differential equation

$$f''(x) + f(x) = x$$

giving $f(x) = A\sin x + B\cos x + x$ for some constants $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$.